# How to load a new view within a view controller when a uibutton is tapped

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm creating a tab-based app. I want one of the tabs to include the following:

-Have a set of UIButtons
-When you click on one of the buttons it loads a view beneath the buttons
-Each button has a different view
-No navigation controller just load the view on the same page without animation
-Still can click on the other buttons

How do I go about doing this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If the views are relatively lightweight, you can put them all into the `.xib` with hidden = YES, then put an `IBOutlet` to each. When you tap a button, hide the others and show the correct one.

If they're more complicated you might also want make some sort of `ViewController`-like object for each one of them to manage state.

You can also create and swap the subviews in code, again keeping around a pointer to each view or you can use `tag`s to identify them.

Comment: Where do I' put the buttons outside all the views or on every view?